# Are there $C^1$ groups that aren't smooth?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I haven't thought too hard about this, so it might be easy. Analysis counterexamples aren't my strong suit.

One slick way of phrasing the definition of a Lie Group is as a group object in the category of smooth manifolds. In particular, this forces the group multiplication to be smooth.

You can also ask for groups in the category of, say, $C^1$ manifolds (or any $C^k$). However we know (by a theorem of Whitney) that any $C^k$ manifold already has smooth structure by restricting the atlas ([though the resulting smooth structure may be noncanonical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769159/are-ck-manifolds-the-same-as-c-infty-manifolds)).

Question: Are there groups whose multiplication is $C^1$ but not $C^2$? What about $C^k$ but not $C^{k+1}$?

It seems like such objects should exist, but I haven't encountered them, and I can't find any by a quick google.

Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301877/are-there-nonsmooth-lie-groups) question is relevant to you?

Comment: There's a good reason you haven't encountered them: a topological manifold that is a topological group automatically has a smooth structure making it a $C^{\infty}$ Lie group.

Comment: Thank you both. Those answer my question ^_^